# Ask gettext about current language and translation source in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, gettext

I initialize `gettext` very simple like this in python3.

```
>>> import gettext
>>> gettext.install('i18n-test', 'locales')
>>> print(_('Hello World!'))
Hallo Welt!
```

Can I ask gettext which current language it uses (must not be the system default  `LANGUAGE`!) and where it opens the `.mo` file from?

I can not see something like this in the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find` function of `gettext` module is what you need. More exactly, it is internally used by the `install` function, so it will return what `install` will use:

> `gettext.install(domain, localedir=None, codeset=None, names=None)` 
>   This installs the function `_()` in Python’s builtins namespace, based on domain, localedir, and codeset which are passed to the function `translation()`...

then

> `gettext.translation(domain, localedir=None, languages=None, class_=None, fallback=False, codeset=None)` 
>   Return a Translations instance based on the domain, localedir, and languages, which are first passed to `find()` to get a list of the associated .mo file paths...

So you should use:

```
file = gettext.find('i18n-test', 'locales')
```

It should return a file name like `localedir/language/LC_MESSAGES/domain.mo`, where `language` is the language selected by gettext.

Comment: Not sure but seems to me that this do not work when a language was used different from the systems locale; e.g. `gettext.translation(languages=['ja', ])` on a German machine. The `gettext.find()` will return the path to the `de` file not `ja`.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs;

> If you use this API you will affect the translation of your entire application globally. Often this is what you want if your application is monolingual, with the choice of language dependent on the locale of your user. If you are localizing a Python module, or if your application needs to switch languages on the fly, you probably want to use the class-based API instead.

So you would probably be better using the [Class-based API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#class-based-api) to do this. Good luck!